# Basics of creating a table and refreshing it via a mysql event

Tags: mysql, mysql-event

My apologies in advance for my display of ignorance.  Is there a way for the event_body of an event to take the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS compdist1.comp_CL1;

CREATE TABLE compdist1.comp_CL1 AS SELECT * FROM compdist1.prices_CL_analysis;
```

I am discovering that only one line is being picked up. (the top one).  Is there a way to make it do both steps? Basically, drop the table and repopulate it from the view prices_CL_analysis.

Comment: Thanks, Erik.  I think you made it appear on 2 separate lines and that was what I thought I had submitted.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap both statements in `BEGIN` and `END`, like:

```
CREATE EVENT e_daily
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 1 DAY
    COMMENT 'Saves total number of sessions then clears the table each day'
    DO
      BEGIN
        INSERT INTO site_activity.totals (time, total)
          SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, COUNT(*)
            FROM site_activity.sessions;
        DELETE FROM site_activity.sessions;
      END
```

Taken from a quick perusal of the [MySQL Create Event page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html).

So, your code might become:

```
CREATE EVENT e_daily
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 1 DAY
    COMMENT 'blah'
    DO
      BEGIN
          DROP TABLE IF EXISTS compdist1.comp_CL1;
          CREATE TABLE compdist1.comp_CL1 
          AS 
          SELECT * 
          FROM compdist1.prices_CL_analysis;
      END
```

Also redefine the MySQL delimiter temporarily before the `CREATE EVENT …` to a different symbol and use the declared symbol at the end of the definition so that MySQL can pass the entire CREATE EVENT statement to the server. Redefine it back to `;` after the definition, like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE EVENT e_daily
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 1 DAY
    COMMENT 'blah'
    DO
      BEGIN
          …
      END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

This is needed when passing compound statements. Since the event body contains more than one statement, you event definition now qualifies as a compound statement. More information at the [MySQL Defining Stored Programs page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-programs-defining.html).

Comment: Thank you very much!  I knew about BEGIN and END b/c I had done some looking up, but I thought this was being entered for me by the tools I was using to create the event (phpmyadmin being one of them).  Now that I've wrapped then as you've shown me, it's working.